# CouchDB replication is not working properly behind a proxy

Tags: apache, couchdb, reverse-proxy

***Note:** Made some updates based on new information. Old ideas have been added as comments below.*
***Note:** Made some updates (again) based on new information. Old ideas have been added as comments below (again).*

We are running two instances of CouchDB on separate computers behind Apache reverse proxies. When attempting to replicate between the two instances:

```
curl -X POST http://user:pass@localhost/couchdb/_replicate -d '{ "source": "db1", "target": "http://user:pass@10.1.100.59/couchdb/db1" }' --header "Content-Type: application/json"
```

(we started using curl to debug the problem)

we receive an error similar to:

```
{"error":"case_clause","reason":"{error,\n    {{bad_return_value,\n         {invalid_json,\n             <<\"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \\\"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\\\">\\n<html><head>\\n<title>404 Not Found</title>\\n</head><body>\\n<h1>Not Found</h1>\\n<p>The requested URL /couchdb/db1/_local/01e935dcd2193b87af34c9b449ae2e20 was not found on this server.</p>\\n<hr>\\n<address>Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat) Server at 10.1.100.59 Port 80</address>\\n</body></html>\\n\">>}},\n     {child,undefined,\"01e935dcd2193b87af34c9b449ae2e20\",\n         {gen_server,start_link,\n             [couch_rep,\n              [\"01e935dcd2193b87af34c9b449ae2e20\",\n               {[{<<\"source\">>,<<\"db1\">>},\n                 {<<\"target\">>,\n                  <<\"http://user:pass@10.1.100.59/couchdb/db1\">>}]},\n               {user_ctx,<<\"user\">>,\n                   [<<\"_admin\">>],\n                   <<\"{couch_httpd_auth, default_authentication_handler}\">>}],\n              []]},\n         temporary,1,worker,\n         [couch_rep]}}}"}
```

So after further research it appears that apache returns this error without attempting to access CouchDB (according to the log files). To be clear when fed the following URL

```
/couchdb/db1/_local/01e935dcd2193b87af34c9b449ae2e20
```

Apache passes the request to CouchDB and returns CouchDB's 404 error. On the other hand when replication occurs the URL actually being passed is

```
/couchdb/db1/_local%2F01e935dcd2193b87af34c9b449ae2e20
```

which apache determines is a missing document and returns its own 404 error for *without* ever passing the request to CouchDB. This at least gives me some new leads but I could still use help if anyone has an answer offhand.

Comment: The issue seems to have something to do with the HTML being returned by the remote server (happens as a source or a target). The rewriting appears to be 'automagical'. The page does not match the 404 presented in the apache error documents (which aren't active anyway). There appear to be similar properties in the Erlang-based INETS library but they're not exactly the same and my attempts to edit the appropriate sections had no results that I could tell.

Any ideas?

Comment: I checked the log files and contrary to the return message, what couch actually sends is "/couchdb/db1/_local%2F01e935dcd2193b87af34c9b449ae2e20" (escaped slash) which results in the same error about HTML being returned while the URL with unescaped slash returns the expect JSON error. This problem does not occur in either situation without the proxy.

This implies the problem is in the proxy but the proxy's ErrorDocument handling is turned off and none of the files listed match anyway. Does anyone have further suggestions?

Comment: At this point, since you are debugging/configuring an Apache httpd reverse proxy, you might try asking on Server Fault. I would imagine those folks eat reverse proxies for breakfast. I updated my answer to talk about paths and escape codes a little.

Answer (score 2):

The source CouchDB (localhost) is telling you that the remote URL was invalid. Instead of a CouchDB response, the source is receiving the **Apache httpd proxy's** file-not-found response.

Unfortunately, you may have some reverse-proxy troubleshooting to do. My first guess is the `Host` header the source is sending to the target. Perhaps it's different from when you connect directly from a third location?

Finally, I think you probably know this, but the path

```
/couchdb/db1/_local%2F01e935dcd2193b87af34c9b449ae2e20
```

Is **not** a standard CouchDB path. By the time CouchDB sees a request, it should have the `/couchdb` stripped, so the query is for a document called `_local%2f...` in the database called `db1`.

Incidentally, it is **very** important not to let the proxy modify the paths before they hit couch. In particular, if you send `%2f` then CouchDB had better receive `%2f` and if you send `/` then CouchDB had better receive `/`.

Comment: I actually checked the file-not-found response of the httpd server and it isn't active and doesn't match. Is there a different set of response files/configurations for the proxy (and do you have any idea where they might be)?  Also, I'll check about the HOST header; thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Well anyway that is definitely **not** a CouchDB 404. If you google that phrase, the results are full of Apache httpd messages. I know, it is very frustrating. Another thing to do is watch the target CouchDB logs and its proxy logs simultaneously during a replication.

Comment: Okay, the error rewriting is almost definitely in the proxy but it doesn't have anything to do with the HOST header. I updated the main question with further details. Any new ideas? I don't understand why it would rewrite the error for one but not the other.

Comment: To clarify the '/couchdb/' is what's sent, not what couch receives, but thank you for the dumbcheck. :-)

Answer (score 1):

From official documentation...

Note that HTTPS proxies are in theory supported but do not work in 1.0.1. This is because 1.0.1 ships with ibrowse version 1.5.5. The CouchDB version in trunk (from where 1.1 will be based) ships with ibrowse version 1.6.2. This later ibrowse contains fixes for HTTPS proxies.

Can you see which version of ibrowse is involved?  Maybe update that ver?

Comment: Noted but not relevant. The error occurs when accessing via HTTP. Incidentally, I am using the latest version of CouchDB which includes updates to proxy behaviors.

Answer (score 1):

Another thought I have is with regard to the SSL certs.  If you don't have any, and I know you don't :), then technically you're doing SSL wrong.  In java we know there are ways around this, but maybe try putting in proper certs since all SSL stuff basically involves certs.

Answer (score 1):

And for my last contribution (today) I would say have you looked through this document which seems highly relevant?

http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Apache_As_a_Reverse_Proxy

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this answer with the hope to help someone who might have been struggling with this issue for more than a week:

I have couchdb v3.1.1 installed
I was obliged to enable/install two modules on IIS to make it work on a proxy:

- corsmodule
- IIS rewrite module V 2

I had to change the settings of SSL:

- require true
- ignore certificates

Additionally I have installed
***Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 and 2010 Redistributable***
to make couchdb service run without restarting.

Hope it helps.